# Having Several Read Operation Values be Appended to Array at Once - Swift & Firebase

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase-realtime-database

in my app's search VC, each table view cell has a profile pic, name, and the corresponding post. I have three separate read operations to get each piece. The problem is that I can't get the variable from each read operation to add to the array - even when it's defined globally. To fix this, I added three separate functions that are called in each read operation, and then are called to append the value to the array. Each post has a key which is what the 'id' is. As you could've guessed I can't get the values from each read operation to all be appended to the array at once - which would explain why some are `<null>`. Here is my code:

```
func a(message:String) -> String{
        print(message)
        let mess = message

        return mess
    }
    func b(url: String) -> String{
        print(url)
        return url
    }
    func c(name:String) -> String {
        print(name)
        let name = name
        return name
    }

    func searchNames(id: String){
        var name = String()
        var message = String()
        var profURL = String()
        Database.database().reference().child("\(UserData().mySchool!)/posts/\(id)/message").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            message = "\(snapshot.value!)"
            self.a(message: message)

//            print("Message:",message)
        })
        Database.database().reference().child("\(UserData().mySchool!)/posts").child("\(id)/username").observe(.value, with: { (username) in
            name = "\(username.value!)"
//            print("user:",name)
            self.c(name: name)
        })

        Database.database().reference().child("\(UserData().mySchool!)/posts/\(id)/profileURL").observe(.value, with: { (url) in
            profURL = "\(url.value!)"
            self.b(url: profURL)
        })

        let x = a
        let y = b
        let z = c
        print("x",x,"y",y,"z",z)
        let user = Person(category: x, name: z, id: id, url: y)
        self.candies.append(user)
        print(message, name,id, profURL)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
```

The idea with the functions(a,b,c) is that they would return the value outside of the read operation and could be used to append the array. The line `print("x",x,"y",y,"z",z)` prints

```
x (Function) y (Function) z (Function)
x (Function) y (Function) z (Function)
x (Function) y (Function) z (Function)
x (Function) y (Function) z (Function)
x (Function) y (Function) z (Function)
x (Function) y (Function) z (Function)
x (Function) y (Function) z (Function)
x (Function) y (Function) z (Function)
x (Function) y (Function) z (Function)
x (Function) y (Function) z (Function)
x (Function) y (Function) z (Function)
x (Function) y (Function) z (Function)
x (Function) y (Function) z (Function)
x (Function) y (Function) z (Function)
x (Function) y (Function) z (Function)
x (Function) y (Function) z (Function)
x (Function) y (Function) z (Function)
x (Function) y (Function) z (Function)
```

This is the structure where I am reading from:
[image]
Any ideas on how to get each individual value out of the read operation and have it be appended to the `Person` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus on making your database structure more efficient instead of focusing on how to patch that inefficiency. Having to make 3 calls to get the data you need is excessive and risky, what happens if one or two of these calls fail?

Have a node for your search where you can get the profile pic, name and message in one call.

Now, if you are set on going ahead with your implementation, what you could do is have a completion handler for each call and nest your calls; once one is completed call the next one, at the end of the last one append everything in your array. But again, I would strongly advise against it!

EDIT: If you have a different vc where the comments load consider creating a seperate node for the comments(-comments --postIdTheCommentBelongsTo ---commentId). Or combine your implementation with my suggestion: keep one or two comments in yours and the rest, store them as I suggested; when the user taps on "view more" make a second call to load the extra comments.

Comment: So far my database structure has served me well up until this point. I edited my question to include a pic of my structure. Technically, all the info is grouped under one node, but I'm probably thinking of something differently than you.

Comment: Right, would you like to give me an example of the functionality? eg. I create a post, 10 people comment on it what is the info you are trying to access?

Comment: In the search vc, I’m trying to display all the posts but I can’t get the info from the read operations at once. Not necessarily commenting - I’m just trying to get the name, profURL, and message from the picture.

Comment: You last child should be the postid, that way you get everything in your snapshot in one call.

Comment: Thanks Do2 that helped me a lot I'll give you a shoutout in the credits for my app lol! #Do2020